# Creating a child theme after numerous edits to parent theme

Tags: php, child-theme, updates

So a quick explanation:

I started messing with Wordpress a couple of years ago, having experience with HTML, CSS and some PHP. At that time I was paid a few hundred bucks to whip together a customized site for someone, which I had done by really manipulating (basically redoing everything but the functional side of things and the basics of the layout).

Fast-forward to today and the same guy wants to pay me to rework his old site a bit, however it has some layout issues (the mobile layout has shifted to the left from center etc. things that I believe will be fixed by a theme update or some tweaking on my part). Now today I would never work on anything without creating a child theme, but now I must redeem myself for my noob mistakes.

My question is: what should I know/do before embarking on safety-proofing everything as I migrate the changes to a child theme? I know that once I do this my layout will look wonky until I re-add widgets, menus etc. Is there anything I may not expect?

I have edited so many different PHP files in this theme that I am going to have to run some sort of scan over the directory to look for changes/differences in the new files as not to lose any of my work.

Any advice is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: No, writing a code that scans the differences would be too complicated. You have 2 options: **1.** compare each file for differences **2.** Start from clean install and add all the whistles back **(recommended)**

Answer (score 1):

If I were you...

1. download original theme. **caution: same version**
2. install git from https://git-scm.com/downloads [*]
3. do `Git Init` **in original theme**, `git add` && `git commit`
4. move `.git` folder (hidden) to **your edited theme** use `git status`, `git diff`... etc
5. Be happy

[*]Git detects all the diferences in your work directory.

ciao

Comment: This is definitely your best option.  If you have something like this where there's only one or two files that need checking you can use [DiffChecker](https://www.diffchecker.com/) instead of making the whole project a git repo